# "in showers" to mean "in large quantity"

Tags: word-usage

Is it idiomatic to say something like:

> She was screaming in showers

I googled around for examples and couldn't find any but as long as the meaning is clear, it's good enough.

Comment: It's not idiomatic in British English. I don't know about other parts of the world. If I saw/heard that phrase I could probably guess the intended meaning, but I wouldn't be certain.

Comment: Things can perhaps *come down* in showers, but one screams *at the top of their lungs*.

Comment: The meaning is clear. Standard garden-variety metaphor.

Comment: Though not a particularly good metaphor.

Comment: Screaming in showers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycho_%281960_film%29#The_shower_scene

Comment: I don't understand what you intend for it to mean. People often sing off-key and loudly while in the shower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Shower](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shower)***  with the meaning you are suggesting, can be used in expressions like:

> - A fall of a group of objects, especially from the sky: a meteor shower; a shower of leaves.
> - An abundant flow; an outpouring: a shower of praise. (AHD)

- "a shower of screams" would be understood but it is not a common idiomatic expressions.  *Large quantity*  applied to 'screaming' would  normally be conveyed with expressions like 'at the top of one's voice' and 'for hours'.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not idiomatic. But just wait because you never know when a pop-singer will use it in a hit single. Then all the kids will be using it.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed is not idiomatic.

Depending on context, you might want to consider any of the following expressions:

***yell one's head off*** and ***yell one's guts out***

> : *Fig.* to yell loud and long. *I was yelling my head off at the football game.* *Stop yelling your guts out and listen to me.* [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/yell)

***wail like a banshee***

> : scream shrilly, as in *Terrified, she wailed like a banshee.* In Irish folklore, a banshee is a spirit in the form of a wailing woman whose appearance is an omen that one member of a family will die. The simile dates from the late 1800s. [AHD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wail)

***[scream/yell] like mad/crazy***

> like crazy: *Informal* to an exceeding degree [AHD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crazy)